# Highlight word or part of the word in text utf8 PHP

Tags: php, search, highlight

i need to highlight the words from text with utf8 for example:

1. Text: Now that we know who you are, Činšot I know who I am. I'm not
   a mistake!

   Word: Čin

   Result: Now that we know who you are, **Čin**šot I know who I am. I'm not
   a mistake!
2. Text: Now that we know who you are, Činšot I know who I am. I'm not
       a mistake!

   Word: Cin

   Result: Now that we know who you are, **Čin**šot I know who I am.
   I'm not
       a mistake!

---

I need that if the word is not containing of utf8 characters it would highlight.

My current code:

```
function highlight($text, $words, $type) {
     preg_match_all('~\p{L}+~iu', $words, $m);
     if(!$m)
          return $text;
     $re = '~\\p{L}}(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\p{L}}~iu';
     return preg_replace($re, '<span id="title_highlight">$0</span>', $text);
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? Server or client or desktop or mobile?

Comment: sorry, PHP i forgot to mention

Comment: You will need to store a bunch of optional unicode characters (or sequences) that cause similar looking characters to display. In your example, there is a code for the lithuanian C with the hat and another for the C without it. I assume you want the lower case versions of these too. You have to search for all of them. Dunno if PHP has some help for this.

Comment: @Lee Meador if i know these characters how can I implement this ? can you show example with one character ? for example Š => S ?